# Executing a php script on database trigger

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

How do I execute a php script on an update in mysql data for the updated columns only.
For example if there is a new entry in a table , I want to execute a php script only on the new entry in the table. So, if a person enters his name and age in the table, an email gets sent using php containing his name and age.

I can create such a php script which takes arguments from command line, I just don't know how to make it execute it on an update/insert trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Typically an update to the database would happen through another PHP script, which would itself launch the emailer script.

If you really need this to happen through a trigger - for example, because the data is being entered directly from the command line SQL client - then take a look at [this FAQ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-B-5-1-10).

Answer (score 0):

Make a trigger that inserts the updated row in another table. Have a script that periodically checks this table for contents and do the work for each row. The script should delete the row when finished.